# Not sure how to get express routing to work

Tags: express, routes

I have a `index.js` file with the following code...

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.use(express.json({ extended: false }));

app.use('/api/users/', require('./users/routes'));

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server started on PORT ${PORT}`));
```

and a `routes.js` file with the following code...

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('test', (req, res) => {
  console.log('im here!')
  res.send('hello from test route!');
});

module.exports = router;
```

my file structure is...

```
server/
  users/
    routes.js
  index.js
```

I am able to start the server with no issues, however, if I try to go to the route `/api/users/test` it does not work and says cannot get that route.

For some reason when I am creating files with the `.js` extension a `.jsx` icon comes up. I am using vscode and feel that this might be the issue but I don't know how to fix it?

As an update in my routes file...

```
router.get('test', (req, res) => {});
```

needs to change to the following...

```
router.get('/test', (req, res) => {});
```

and in my `index.js` file

```
app.use('/api/users', require('./users/routes'));
```

basically, adding the slash before the test and taking away the slash after users.

I do not know why that would be an issue but it now works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In routes.js:

```
router
    .get ('/test',(req, res) => {
    console.log('im here!')
    res.send('hello from test route!');
});
```

You just forgot the slash in front of your route.
You should now see your response @ http://localhost:5000/api/users/test.

Comment: So, I know that I can use require within the `app.use`, regardless, I tried what you mentioned but still nothing. I really think it has to do with vscode making my js file a jsx file, but I'm not positive about this and I also don't know how to fix that

Comment: Actually, the weirdest thing happened. After trying your thing and then hitting control z to get back what I had it now works. I am super confused as to why and my files still show as if it were `jsx` so I guess that is not the issue. At least it works now but I really do not understand what was wrong before

Comment: Yes, sure! The first point was rather cosmetic. Also you don't have to use router.route and pass in next. Actually you just forgot the slash before your test route: .get ('/test',(req, res) <--also works..

Comment: Regarding the jsx problem: Can't you just select another language mode by clicking on "JavaScript" in the blue bar at the bottom of vs code and select JavaScript (javascript) instead of JavaScript React?

Comment: Yes, I can. Thanks for pointing that out. I didn't realize and ended up changing some settings on my vscode when working on a Django app so ever since that it changed.